# What command to turn HDMI on or off

Tags: hdmi

I have a intel NUC and a CEC compatible TV. On a raspberry pi I can switch the screen off and on using the vgcemd command on raspbian.

How would I do that on ubuntu 20.04 on a intel nuc. This command does not exist.

It for a Magic Mirror project.

Comment: I doubt CEC is connected on Intel NUC. The RPi is one of a very small number of devices that have that.

Comment: For my NUC8i3BEH, the documentation specs mention 'Onboard CEC control from the embedded controller via HDMI cable and BIOS setup'.

Comment: but how do you use it from within the OS?

Comment: The only thing I was able te achieve is that the TV turns on the nuc. Here are the bios settings: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023500/intel-nuc/intel-nuc-kits.html